# Select from multiple select_list elements

Tags: ruby, css-selectors, watir, watir-webdriver

Hi I wanted to know how I can select a certain index in all select_list boxes on the screen. I was able to make them flash with this line of code:

```
browser.elements(:class => "level").each { |e| e.flash }
```

Due to lack of experience I am unable to figure out how to actually select the same index (the last option from drop down) from all the boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm following correctly, you want to select the last option for multiple dropdown menus.

Given some contrived HTML:

```
<select>
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two">Two</option>
  <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="four">Four</option>
  <option value="five">Five</option>
  <option value="six">Six</option>
</select>
```

You can user the [`select_lists`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Container#select_lists-instance_method) method to collect the available select lists, and then iterate over that collection and [select](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Option#select-instance_method) the [last](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-last) option for each:

```
lists = browser.select_lists

lists.each do |list|
  list.options.last.select
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Accomplished what I needed. Appreciate both answers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe grab each select_list, map the value to an array and grab the last element in the array.

```
browser.select_lists(:class => "level").each do |e|
  content = e.options.map(&:value)
  lastElement = content[-1]
end
```